# How do I resolve this error?

Tags: google, google-search-console

I found my website on Google recently, and the sublinks underneath the search entity title contains a suspicious link to Viagra tablets:

[image]

Professionals are observing my website all the time. How can I get rid of this spammy link as soon as possible? Can I manually tell Google what links to place there?

Comment: Strangely, the link with text "Viagra tablets" still links to a URL on my site: "/calendar.html".

Comment: Do you have a Sitemap? What's the `title` of "
/calendar.html"? Also, your site is 404ing for me ;)

Comment: I would strongly suspect that your site has been compromised and infected. You should check this (unless you are selling Viagra).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are called [SiteLinks](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334) -

> The links shown below some of Google's search results, called
>   sitelinks, are meant to help users navigate your site. Our systems
>   analyze the link structure of your site to find shortcuts that will
>   save users time and allow them to quickly find the information they're
>   looking for.

[image: Sitelinks]

To explore your SiteLinks, you can use the SiteLink demotion tool:

1. On the [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) Home page, click the site you want.
2. Under `Configuration`, click `Sitelinks`.
3. In the For this search result box, complete the URL for which you don't want a specific sitelink URL to appear. ([How to find the right URL.](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=63758))
4. In the Demote this sitelink URL box, complete the URL of the sitelink you want to demote.